# PyPdf2 extracting text with n in front of certain letters

Tags: python, join, renaming, pypdf

This may just be due to `PyPdf2's` extract text function but when I run the code below in order to rename the files, a lot of the most common words come out like "Nthe", "Nfrom" and "Ncommunications". I'm not sure what I can do to stop this happening or alternatively how to work around it.

What causes a problem like this?

Where are the N's coming from?

Other PDFs do perfectly what I want so I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
import PyPDF2
import re
from collections import Counter
import os.path

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
files = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(('.pdf','.PDF')), files)

for file in files:
    pdfFileObj = open('{0}'.format(file), 'rb') #Open the File
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) #Read the file
    frequency = {} #Create dict
    ignore = {'the','a','if','in','it','of','or','and','for','can','that','are','this','your','you','will','not','have','its','with','need','has','from','more'} #Ignore dese ones

    print "Number of Pages %s " % pdfReader.numPages #Print Num Pages
    word_list = []
    for i in range(pdfReader.numPages): 
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i) # Get the first page
        word_list.append(pageObj.extractText()) #Add the pages together

    match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{3,15}\b', str(word_list)) #Find the text
    cnt = Counter()
    for words in match_pattern: #Start counting the frequency
        words.lower() # Lower Case Words
        if words not in ignore: #Ignore common words
            count = frequency.get(words,0) #Start the count?
            frequency[words] = count + 1 #Add one
    fl = sorted(frequency, key=frequency.__getitem__, reverse = True)[:3] #Sort according to frequency

    pdfFileObj.close() #Close the PDF
    newtitle = ' '.join(map(str,fl, )).title() #Join the title list together

    try:
        print newtitle #Print the title
        os.rename('{0}'.format(file), '{0}.pdf'.format(newtitle))#Rename the file
    except:
        print "Unable to Rename File"
```

Comment: Just a hint: do those words occur after a line break? For instance: "blah blah blah (new line) communications blah blah".

It may happen that the new line character (`\n`) is not being correctly stripped.

Also, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try to nail down where the problem seems to be and include that in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much iled, I'm going to try and work out how I can strip out the new line character.

Comment: If you find out that it is where the problem is, you can use `.strip()`, like so `'\n'.strip()`.